# Copy Files and directories with su command on rooted device

Tags: android, root, su

Similar Questions are often asked here, but I can´t figure out, what exactly I have to do. This is not a duplicate, because the solutions on many threads here are not what I am looking for or doesn´t work for me. I want to copy files and directories to a folder inside the `/data/` folder. So, I made a lot of search on SO and Googled for hours. But all the threads I found are not clear enough and don´t let me get what I want. I also found this Blogs, but that doesn´help me.

http://su.chainfire.eu/

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1694251

**What I have tried**

I am able to copy a directory to sd from the `/data/` directory without need a su command and it works well just with java code. First question: Is root permission not neccessary for copying from `/data/` folder to sd card?
The next step I have done is, to execute su command like this:

```
Process pp  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su cat "+originDir+" > "+targetDir);
```

Where orginDir is the path on sd card from a file and the targetDir is the folder inside the `/data/` directory as `Strings`, for example:

```
/data/test/testfile.txt
```

The problem here is, I can copy this file, but it has 0 Bytes. So what I am doing wrong?

**What I want**

1. I want to copy a file from sd card to `/data/` directory
2. I want to create a folder on `/data/` directory
3. I want t o copy a whole directory to `/data/` directory

I have searched a lot, but I can´t find a good tutorial for using su command to write files to that directory. Also, is there a list anywhere with all in Android available su commands that can be executed programmatically? Belive me, I am not a lazy developer, I have searched many things, but I hadn´t find a good tutorial for this.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ths copy linux command and add -r (recursive) switch to it `cp -r /source/ /target/`. It will create target if it does not exists

But prior to that you need to make your system is writable

```
mount -o remount,rw /system 
cp -r /source/ /target/
mount -o remount,ro /system #Don't forget to do this, even if everything else fails!!!!
```

**EDIT:** According to comments below, this solution should only be used when targeting relatively new devices

Comment: OK, I will try. But I read about that the cp command doesn´t work on every device. Is this true?

Comment: I don't know anything about that. Check you second link, it is in the list of terminal commands without busybox installed

Comment: cp is a comparatively recent addition to stock android

Comment: Really? A big congratulations to the guy who put it there and a big slap to the face to the guy who didn't put it there in the first release of android.

Comment: @ChrisStratton-and do You know since which API it is available?

Comment: I tried it, but does not work. I got Huaweis Ascend Mate 7 with Android 4.4 . I think at this API, cp -r should be available....

Comment: It works on all of my rooted devices, but they all have custom roms installed and they are not outdated either :/

Comment: Now I get it work for files, but directories don´t work. I have the correct path, what could be the problem?

Comment: Getting  `/system not in /proc/mounts` when running `mount -o remount,rw /system`